# How to reload cached data effectively

Tags: php, caching

Basically I'll be caching all user input data for this (For example I'll be caching user comments).

I'm using [**Simple PHP Cache**](https://github.com/cosenary/Simple-PHP-Cache).
Now what I'd be doing is running something like (*pseudo code*):

```
$cache = new Cache(page-specific-cache);

if(hasNewComments()) {
    $cache->erase('comments');
    $cache->store('comments', array(/*array of comments...*/), 60);
}
//...show comments and stuff
```

Now my question is: Should I run the above block of code or should I try doing something like the following code where I also check if the cache has expired and if it has then regenerate it? Which seems a bit overboard in this case?

```
$cache = new Cache(page-specific-cache);

if((hasNewComments()) || ($cache->isCached('comments') && $cache->isExpired('comments'))) {
    $cache->erase('comments');
    $cache->store('comments', array(/*array of comments...*/), 60);
}
//...show comments and stuff
```

---

**Notes**

the `isExpired()` method doesn't come with the class, I created it myself and this is what it looks like:

```
public function isExpired($key) {
    if (false != $this->_loadCache()) {
      $cachedData = $this->_loadCache();
      return $this->_checkExpired($cachedData[$key]['time'], $cachedData[$key]['expire']);
    }
  }
```

Comment: In the code you show, you're never actually *reading* from the cache... there's no point in caching if you're never reading from it. Typically you read from the cache if it exists (it should cease to exist by itself when it expires), then you refresh the data.

Comment: @deceze Sorry I haven't included that part. Basically the cache checks are done and then the reads (`retrieve`) is done after to append to a template variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently you're checking for new comments before you try to use the cache. That makes the cache pretty pointless. The point of a cache is to take some load off of a certain system (like constantly fetching comments from the database), in exchange for the possibility of having outdated data for a while. Your logic should be this (pseudocode):

```
comments = cache.get('comments')
if !comments
    comments = database.get('comments')
    cache.store(key='comments', value=comments, expires=3600)

print comments
```

The cache should return `false`/`null`/whatever if the data has either never been cached before or if it's expired. If your cache doesn't have an automatic expiry system, save a timestamp with the comments array and do the check manually after you get the cached data back.

Again, the tradeoff of a cache is that you may display outdated data while there's already new data in the database. How and when to expire a cache is one of the two great problems in programming (the other being naming stuff).

Either you do not care about having outdated comments for a certain amount of time; in that case choose your expiry time wisely.

Otherwise, a good strategy is to never have the cache expire by itself, but explicitly delete the cache when a new comment is posted. That ensures that you always have up to date data without having to constantly check. However, if your frequency of comments is so high that the cache is permanently being deleted, there's little point in having a cache in the first place.

It's all tradeoffs. Choose your sweet spot.

Comment: Thank you, that was actually exactly what I was after!

Comment: Would it be good to store a count of comments in the cache and then `if cache.get()` -> `database check comment counts against cache comments count` -> `if higher update cache and serve` -> `otherwise just serve`?

Comment: That may be another tradeoff. Put *some* load on the database, but not the full load of fetching everything if it's unnecessary. I'd probably rather go with the timestamp of the latest comment instead of a count. But whether this actually does anything useful in terms of speeding things up is another question. Benchmark it.